# toggle boolean property in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a checkbox in my view

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="trackers[tracker._id].enable" ng-click="toggleTracker(tracker._id);"/>
```

And a function in my controller

```
$scope.toggleTracker = function(trackerId){
    $scope.trackers[trackerId].enable = !$scope.trackers[trackerId].enable;
    console.log($scope.trackers[trackerId].enable)
}
```

But each time I check the box the `enable` property does not change. What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: please show more code. also if you are using ng-model - you shouldn't need to have a click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have ng-model connected to the input it should change when you click. Then you also have the ng-click so it changes back to the first value.

Just remove the ng-click and your good.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use both ng-model and an ng-click function toggling the enable state. Maybe it overrides and negate the toggle because they are executed one after the other.

Just use the ng-model property and it should work.